# NHibernate update using composite key

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, composite-key

I have a table defnition as given below:

### License

```
ClientId
Type
Total
Used
```

ClientId and Type together uniquely identifies a row. I have a mapping file as given below:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
  <class name="Acumen.AAM.Domain.Model.License, Acumen.AAM.Domain" lazy="false" table="License">
<id name="ClientId" access="field" column="ClientID" />
<property name="Total" access="field" column="Total"/>
<property name="Used" access="field" column="Used"/>
<property name="Type" access="field" column="Type"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If a client used a license to create a user, I need to update the Used column in the table. As I set ClientId column as the id column for this table in the mapping xml, I am getting TooManyRowsAffectedException.

could you please let me know how to set a composite key at mapping level so that NHibernate can udpate based on ClientId and Type.

Something like:  Update License SET Used=Used-1 WHERE ClientId='xxx' AND Type=1

Please help.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you primary key is composite, your mapping should reflect that, and your class needs to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Also, if `ClientId` is the primary key of your `Client` entity, you should map it as `many-to-many`, not just an Id.

Also, why are you specifying `lazy="false"`? Are you aware of the implications?

Also, why map everything with `access="field"`? Do the properties have some special logic?

This is a revised mapping considering everything I just wrote. Feel free to ignore those parts that don't apply :-)

```
<class name="Acumen.AAM.Domain.Model.License, Acumen.AAM.Domain" table="License">
  <composite-id>
    <key-many-to-one name="Client" column="ClientID" />
    <key-property name="Type" />
  </composite-id>
  <property name="Total" />
  <property name="Used" />
</class>
```

Comment: +1 Good solution, and visual example of the mapping, excellent! =)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a composite-id

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid

Answer (score 1):

As the other comrades mentioned above, you have to use a composite-id, which is not a best but acceptable practice.

On the other hand, you can simply write an [update interceptor](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-interceptors) and make sure your Type = 1 within it.

Here are some link about the topic to help you see clear in this.

1. [Elegant code : Implementing NHibernate Interceptors](http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/15/implementing-nhibernate-interceptors/)
2. [NHibernate Documentation : Interceptors](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-interceptors)
3. [Sample NHibernate IInterceptor implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/NHibernate_IInterceptor.aspx)
4. [Enterprise .NET Community : NHibernate Part 2](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=NHibernateP2) (Scroll down to : **Interceptors and Persistent Lifecycle**)
5. [NHibernate Interceptor Auditing Inserted Object Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892220/nhibernate-interceptor-auditing-inserted-object-id) (SO question)

The main advantage of using interceptors over a composite key is that it doesn't break your DBRM and provides a definitely more flexible solution, without "polluting" your mapping file which will more precisely represent your model.